# plotly radar chart - I need to set some attributes

Tags: python, plotly, radar-chart

I have this code as follows;

```
self.fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
            r=_r, 
            theta=_theta, 
            fill="toself", 
            line=_line, 
            name=self.name))
        self.fig.update_layout(
            polar=dict(
                radialaxis=dict(
                visible=True,
                range=[0, 100],
                linecolor=black,
                gridcolor=black,
                dtick=25
                )),
            showlegend=False
            )
```

Which displays the following chart:

[image]

There are a number of things I would like to do and I cannot find how to do it. I would like to:

1. Close the line
2. Replace the white lines between the centre and the edge of the circle with black lines
3. Have smaller labels and/or angle them

How do I do this, I can't find it in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dummy data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

tdf = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "code": {0: "mo", 1: "tu", 2: "we", 3: "th", 4: "fr", 5: "sa", 6: "su"},
        "value": {0: 20.3, 1: 23.6, 2: 21.3, 3: 22.6, 4: 10.8, 5: 0.9, 6: 0.5},
    }
)
```

Plot code based on documentation:

- https://plotly.com/python/radar-chart/#radar-chart-with-plotly-express
- https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/polar/

```py
polarfig = px.line_polar(tdf, r="value", theta="code", line_close=True)  # 1. Close the line: line_close=true
polarfig.update_polars(angularaxis_gridcolor="Black", radialaxis_gridcolor="Black") # 2. Replace the white lines
polarfig.update_polars(angularaxis_tickfont_size=10,angularaxis_tickangle=50) # 3. Make text smaller and at an angle
polarfig.show()
```

[image]

To add that to a trace you can do:

```py
fig.add_trace(polarfig.data[0])
```

You then need to do all the `update_polars` calls on `fig` instead of `polarfig`.